# What is the difference between tantalum and aluminum capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, motor-controller

There are two different motor control modules in the images. Different capacitors are used in both modules. As far as I know, the intended use of these capacitors; when the motor is turned on or off, to avoid supply voltage drop.

So what's the point of using a polymer or tantalum capacitor? What is the difference between them? I want to use polymer when designing my own circuit because polymer is cheaper, will I have any problems?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's mostly chemistry. Some chemistries allow larger capacitance values, some allow lower ESR. Tantalum is expensive because it's one of them rare earth metals, so nowadays you'd pick ceramic capacitors over tantalum unless you have specialized requirements.

Comment: @Lundin, Then it's okay to use aluminum polymer. Thanks

Comment: Unless you have specialized requirements use whatever is cheapest and fulfils your tolerance. When it comes to large bulk caps, then tolerance and temperature stability typically won't matter at all. Life time might, though.

Comment: @Lundin: Tantalum is **not** a [rare earth metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rare-earth_element).

Comment: @Curd Fair enough, but like rare earth metals, the price tends to yo-yo and overall they are very expensive nowadays - wasn't always like that.

Comment: See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/613523/what-is-the-use-case-for-a-tantalum-capacitor/614014#614014

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use case for a tantalum capacitor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/613523/what-is-the-use-case-for-a-tantalum-capacitor)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tantalum capacitors are usually smaller, and can have a longer lifetime if treated properly. However, they're more expensive and have more dangerous failure modes if they go bad--tantalum caps are pretty sensitive to overvoltage, and that overvoltage makes them fail short. When they short, that makes them pull a lot of current and, usually, ignite.

Standard aluminum capacitors also tend to fail short, but when they heat up, they tend to build pressure and then vent as the liquid electrolyte boils. If the safety vent fails to burst, they may explode rather violently, though.

Aluminum polymer capacitors I'm less familiar with, however--I couldn't tell you what their failure modes are. They have a solid electrolyte like tantalum capacitors, but they tend to come in a non-flammable metal can. There are also hybrid polymer capacitors, which use both a liquid and a solid electrolyte; those would probably fail by venting just like the standard aluminum caps.

In the modern day, there's usually little reason to use tantalum capacitors. MLCCs are available in quite large capacitances these days, and when you need something bigger, aluminum is usually cheaper even considering the larger board area they need compared to tantalum--tantalum caps are expensive.

Comment: Datasheets for precision/low noise parts will sometimes request a tantalum (or electrolytic) cap specifically because it has a higher ESR than a MLCC. This can prevent a LC resonance in the power line.

Comment: @AdamV.Steele Other datasheets may specify a tantalum cap specifically because it has a lower ESR than an aluminum one, and the datasheet was written long enough ago that the idea of a 22 μF ceramic capacitor was laughable and would never be mentioned as a possibility (and al-poly caps were still a decade or two away)--I've seen this a number of times in datasheets for older linear regulators. It's worth reading more of the datasheet to see specifically why they recommend tantalum.

Comment: No, it is for the reason I stated. See e.g.: "Hot-Plugging Safety" section of LTC8065 (buck converter)  (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltm8065.pdf) You can also see the data sheet for LTC2485 and confirmation with Analog Devices engineers here: https://ez.analog.com/data_converters/precision_adcs/f/q-a/577847/why-does-the-ltc2485-datasheet-say-to-use-a-tantalum-vcc-bypass-capacitor/517652

Comment: @AdamV.Steele I am not disputing that. I am saying that for *some* datasheets it's one way, and for others it's the opposite.